# Can't do PrintScreen with open menu. Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, print-screen

I got problem when opening any menu (e.g. wi-fi status menu at the top panel) cannot shot print screen. In any other case when menus are not active `Print` works just fine with default settings `xfce4-screenshooter -f`. `Alt+Print` with command `xfce4-screenshooter -w` also didn't work.

Moreover when I try do print screen with open menu in Firefox, first menu is hidden and then image is captured without opened menu.